# SQL - set min or max value in calculation

Tags: sql, select

My database *items* contains their specifications (id, name, length, height, weight, quantity, etc).

I want to

```
SELECT id, name, length*3 + height*5 as 'newVar' 
FROM items 
ORDER BY newVar DESC
```

However, in order for my formulas to work in the calculation of `newVar`, if 'length' is smaller than 10, I want it to reflected as 10 in the calculation. The same goes for 'height': if it is greater than 10, I need it to be reflected as 10 in the calculation.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplish it with a couple of `CASE` conditions which return `10` if `length` or `height` are `< 10` or `> 10` respectively.

```
SELECT
  id,
  name,
  ((CASE WHEN length < 10 THEN 10 ELSE length END) * 3 + 
  (CASE WHEN height > 10 THEN 10 ELSE height END) * 5)  AS newVar
FROM items
ORDER BY newVar DESC
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2bfb1/2

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `IF` (depending on your RDBMS):

```
SELECT id, 
    name, 
    if(length<10,10,length)*3 + if(height>10,10,height)*5 as 'newVar' 
FROM items 
ORDER BY newVar DESC
```

Or you can use `CASE`:

```
SELECT id, 
    name, 
    case when length<10 then 10 else length end * 3 + 
    case when height>10 then 10 else height end * 5 as 'newVar' 
FROM items 
ORDER BY newVar DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be simpler:

```
SELECT id, name, GREATEST(length, 10) * 3 + LEAST(height, 10) * 5 AS newVar
FROM   items
ORDER  BY newVar DESC
```

`GREATEST` and `LEAST` are not in the SQL standard, but most RDBMS have them.